# Android - How would I go about dynamically changing a clickListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have an array of Buttons, and one fo them is the correct answer, while the other 3 are incorrect.  on each question, however, the correct button changes.  How would I go about updating my click listener?  It seems like a simple enough problem maybe I just can't see the clear answer here...

Here is my code so far, thanks in advance:

```
int correctIndex=newQuestion(questionTextView,answerButtons);//CREATES A NEW QUESTION and returns the correct index (0-3);

answerButtons[correctIndex].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        correctDialog(questionTextView,answerButtons);
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    if (j != correctIndex) {
        answerButtons[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongDialog(questionTextView, answerButtons);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `if (j != correctIndex) {` into the `onClick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a generic listener that you can add to all of the buttons and within that listener handle the logic for determining which one is correct as needed. For example:

```
class YourListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int correctButtonId;

    public YourListener(int correctButtonId) {
        this.correctButtonId = correctButtonId;
    }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == correctButtonId) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

You can then set all of your `n` buttons to have this listener, and from outside the listener you can set the id of the correct button as needed.

Such as

```
// this is the id of the button that is correct, where x represents its index, which you know ahead of time
int id = answerButtons[x].getId();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     answerButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new YourListener(id));
}
```

Edit to answer: how to call a method (in your case, `correctDialog` for example) from inside the listener.

One way is to make the listener an inner class inside your activity. So you have something (not tested, give it a try) like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private class YourListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView;
        private Button[] buttons;
        private int correctButtonId;
        public YourListener(TextView textView, Button[] buttons, int correctButtonId) {
            this.textView = textView;
            this.buttons = buttons;
            this.correctButtonId = correctButtonId;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == correctButtonId) {
                MainActivity.this.correctDialog(textView, buttons);
            } else {
                MainActivity.this.wrongDialog(textView, buttons);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as someone who is new to android, what does the setCorrectButtonId function do?  Also, doesn't the onClick is by itself.  This listens for all buttons?

Comment: @microflakes the `setCorrectButtonId(int)` was a method no longer present after an edit. A setter method is used to set the value of a private field. The code has since been changed to initialize this value directly in the constructor.

Comment: Hold on how does 'id' get updated though??  Won't it just get an id once and then never change? EDIT:  I think what I'm looking for is a loop that creates new onClickListen every time, but I need it to wait for a button to be pressed.  Does that make sense?

Comment: To call a method from that listener you can put the listener as an inner class and call the outer class's method from inside it. For example, from inside your listener, `MainActivity.this.yourMethod()`. If you don't want to do it that way, either make a util / helper / service to do it for you and put that object as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: If you need to update the id inside the listener from outside the listener, you need a set method like the one that was present before cricket_007's edit.

Comment: But everytime I click a button, the id needs to change.  Basically I have a quiz app that shows a question and 4 buttons.  Upon clicking one of them, a dialog says wrong or right, then updates the textView and buttons for a new question.  I'm pretty sure I need some kind of loop, I just don't know how to structure it

Answer (score 0):

I would set the same clickListener for all buttons, and move the logic there. Just check if button's index in array is the same as correct answer's index, no need to update clickListeners or set different.